# Express and mongodb (intermediate value) is not a constructor

Tags: mongodb, express, react-native, redux

I am trying to register a new user in my db.
I am using redux as well for this.

I am confused on what the error message is indicating is the problem.
I am confronted with the 500 server error and this line to follow?:

'(intermediate value) is not a constructor'

To give you a deeper understanding as to where this might be occurring, I have pasted some important parts of my code that initiates this sequence of events that lead to this.

Here's my action:

```
 accountApi.register(
  email,
  password,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  (errObj, resObj) => {
    if (errObj) {
      return dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAILED,
        payload: new Error(errObj.detail)
      });
    }

    const { token } = resObj;

    storage.save(JWT_TOKEN, token, err => {
      if (err) {
        return dispatch({
          type: REGISTER_USER_FAILED,
          payload: err
        });
      }

      return dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: true
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Here's the api route:

```
const body = {
email,
password,
firstName,
lastName,
date: today,
};
  const ROUTE = "register";
  const url = BASE_ROUTE + ROUTE;
  client.post({ url, body }, cb);
}
```

inside API:

```
async function register(req, res) {
req.checkBody('email').notEmpty().isEmail();
req.checkBody('password')
.notEmpty()
.isAscii()
.isLength({ min: 8 });
req.checkBody('firstName')
.notEmpty()
.isAscii()
.isLength({ min: 3, max: 15 });
req.checkBody('lastName')
.notEmpty()
.isAscii()
.isLength({ min: 3, max: 15 });
 });

 const validationErrors = await req.getValidationResult();
 if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.status(400).send(responses.validatorResponse(validationErrors));
 }

 const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
 const userDoc = await accountManager.register(email, password, firstName, 
 lastName, false);
 return res.status(200).send({ token: jwtHelper.createToken(userDoc) });
 }
```

in accountmanger:

```
async function register(email, password, firstName, lastName, isAdmin) {
  const associationDoc = await Association.getDocumentByEmail(email);

  if (!associationDoc) {
    throw new new Error('Unable to register user. User is not associated with 
any organization yet.')();
  }

  const teamDoc = await 
Team.getDefaultTeamForOrganization(associationDoc.organizationId);
 const hashedPassword = account.hashPassword(password);

  const data = {
    firstName: firstName.toLowerCase(),
    lastName: lastName.toLowerCase(),
    email,
    isAdmin,
    fullName: `${firstName.toLowerCase()} ${lastName.toLowerCase()}`,
    teamId: teamDoc._id,
    hashedPassword,
    registrationStatus: REGISTRATION_STATUSES.NEW_REGISTRATION,
    lastSeen: dates.today(),
  };

  return User.create(data);
}
```

And inside user model:

`async function create(data) {
  return new Model(data).save();
}`

I use postman to send the api calls with all the proper info but I keep getting this error message back:

(intermediate value) is not a constructor

Comment: Which line is it telling you that error is on? You should get a stack dump telling you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am using a debugger and that is the response it is providing. (its not crashing) but let me try and see if I can acquire a stack dump.